# Dialog in Angular isn't displaying the template

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I followed the Angular Tour of Heroes tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial and I wanted to try adding a button that triggers a dialog on the dashboard (https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview). However, when I press the Test Dialog button, an empty/blank dialog pops up and it's a long, skinny box that shows up on the left side of my screen taking up full height. I don't know why it isn't displaying the html from DialogtestComponent. Here is my code related to the dialog:

dialogtest.component.html

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Dialog with elements</h2>

<mat-dialog-content>This dialog showcases the title, close, content and actions elements.</mat-dialog-content>

<mat-dialog-actions>

  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Close</button>

</mat-dialog-actions>
```

dialogtest.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';

import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

 

@Component({

  selector: 'app-dialogtest',

  templateUrl: './dialogtest.component.html',

  styleUrls: ['./dialogtest.component.css']

})

export class DialogtestComponent implements OnInit {
 
  constructor(public dialoRef: MatDialogRef<DialogtestComponent>, private fb: FormBuilder) { }
 

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

}
```

dashboard.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material/dialog';

import { DialogtestComponent } from '../dialogtest/dialogtest.component';

import { Hero } from '../hero';

import { HeroService } from '../hero.service';

 

@Component({

  selector: 'app-dashboard',

  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',

  styleUrls: [ './dashboard.component.css' ]

})

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  heroes: Hero[] = [];


  constructor(private dialo: MatDialog, private heroService: HeroService) { }
 

  ngOnInit() {

    this.getHeroes();

  }


  getHeroes(): void {

    this.heroService.getHeroes()

      .subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes.slice(1, 5));

  }


  openDialog() {

    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

    //dialogConfig.disableClose = true;

    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;

    dialogConfig.width = '100%';

    this.dialo.open(DialogtestComponent, dialogConfig);

    const dialoRef = this.dialo.open(DialogtestComponent, dialogConfig);

  }

}
```

dashboard.component.html

```
<h2>Top Heroes</h2>

<div class="heroes-menu">

  <a *ngFor="let hero of heroes"

    routerLink="/detail/{{hero.id}}">

    {{hero.name}}

  </a>
  
  <button style="float: right;" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="openDialog()">Test Dialog</button>

</div>
<app-hero-search></app-hero-search>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

 

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes/heroes.component';

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail/hero-detail.component';

import { MessagesComponent } from './messages/messages.component';

import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component'; // <-- NgModel lives here

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

import { InMemoryDataService } from './in-memory-data.service';

import { HeroSearchComponent } from './hero-search/hero-search.component';

import { DialogtestComponent } from './dialogtest/dialogtest.component';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';

 

@NgModule({

  declarations: [

    AppComponent,

    HeroesComponent,

    HeroDetailComponent,

    MessagesComponent,

    DashboardComponent,

    HeroSearchComponent,

    DialogtestComponent

  ],

  imports: [

    BrowserModule,

    AppRoutingModule,

    HttpClientModule,

    FormsModule,

    MatDialogModule,

    HttpClientModule,

    HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(

      InMemoryDataService, { dataEncapsulation: false }

    ),

    BrowserAnimationsModule

  ],

  providers: [],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent],

  entryComponents: [

    DialogtestComponent

  ]

})

export class AppModule { }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I looked in the console when I tested the dialog button and I saw I was getting a NullInjectorError. The fix was to add `import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'` to app.module.ts and add it to imports.

Answer (score 0):

Here,

```
openDialog() {

    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

    //dialogConfig.disableClose = true;

    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;

    dialogConfig.width = '100%';

    this.dialo.open(DialogtestComponent, dialogConfig);

    const dialoRef = this.dialo.open(DialogtestComponent, dialogConfig);

  }
```

you opened dialog two times

It should be

```
openDialog() {

    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

    //dialogConfig.disableClose = true;

    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;

    dialogConfig.width = '100%';


    const dialoRef = this.dialo.open(DialogtestComponent, dialogConfig);

  }
```

You gave width as 100% (`dialogConfig.width = '100%';`). However max-width of dialog is `80vw` by default. And if content is large that modal height & width will grow. In your case the content of modal is few lines that's why it appears small. Instead give 100% width try to give `dialogConfig.width = '250px'`

You can see live example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-dialog)

Refer more about Angular Material Dialog [here](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api)

Comment: I updated openDialog() with your fix, but I get the same result. I tried changing dialogConfig.width to 250px, 100px, 50px, and 1000px. Is there anything else that would cause this?

Answer (score 0):

In your openDialog try returning dialogRef so it initiates the property, and add a subscription to it, like this:

```
openDialog() {

const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

//dialogConfig.disableClose = true;

dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;

dialogConfig.width = '100%';


const dialoRef = this.dialo.open(DialogtestComponent, dialogConfig);

return dialoRef.afterClosed() 
}
```

Otherwise you're just setting your const to dialoRef open, you're not really telling it that it has to do that.

Comment: I tried returning dialoRef.afterClosed() and added a subscription to it, but I got the same result. I added `return dialoRef.afterClosed().subscribe( data => console.log("dialog output")` Is there something else I'm doing wrong?